# npm bundleDependency leads to errors in npm list

Tags: npm, build, dependencies, bundle, publish

**SETUP**

3 projects:

*Project A*: Used by *Project B*.

*Project B*: Installs *Project A* from cdn and includes it the package via `bundleDependencies: ["projectA"]` in its `package.json`

*Project C*: Installs *Project B* from cdn.

**ISSUE:**

if i now run `npm list --all` from within *Project C* i get the following erorr-message:

`@project-a invalid: "project-a.tgz" from node_modules/project-b`

If i remove the bundleDependencies property it works, but for my usecase i want to include project A in project B's publishment. Any idea on how to fix this?